# Setup VSTS Continuous Integration (CI) for ASP.NET Core Devextreme project

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-1.0, devextreme

I have tried to setup the Continuous Integration (CI) in  VSTS for the ASP.NET core project developed using [Devextreme](https://js.devexpress.com/).

I have checked the NuGet.config file in the project, seems the devextreme-controls-netcore is referred from the local machine.

**NuGet.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="devextreme-controls-netcore" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 17.1\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have created a build definition in VSTS for this project and queued a build. I am getting error while restoring the packages.

**Log file from VS:**

```
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0089440Z ##[section]Starting: Restore
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z Version      : 1.0.2
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-11-17T11:26:33.0279221Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-17T11:26:34.6038344Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore d:\a\3\s\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp.csproj
2017-11-17T11:26:42.2434595Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\3\s\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp.csproj...
2017-11-17T11:26:42.2434595Z   Restoring packages for d:\a\3\s\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp.csproj...
2017-11-17T11:26:42.2434595Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\NuGet.targets(102,5): **error : The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 17.1\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore' doesn't exist.** [d:\a\3\s\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp.csproj]
2017-11-17T11:26:42.6496133Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-11-17T11:26:42.6496133Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\3\s\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp\DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp.csproj
2017-11-17T11:26:42.6536144Z ##[section]Finishing: Restore
```

How to build the devextreme-controls-netcore is VSTS to setup CI.

Please suggest a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: @Daniel Mann I am using hosted agent vs2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, based on this thread: [DevExtreme.AspNet.Core is not available in NuGet repository](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T524333/devextreme-aspnet-core-is-not-available-in-nuget-repository), the core package is published on their private NuGet repository (`https://nuget.devexpress.com/{feed-authorization-key}/api`), so you can retrieve the packages from that private NuGet repository if you have the authorization key.

Secondly, you can add the related packages (in `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 17.1\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore`) to the source control, then map it to the build agent (Get source) and change the value in NuGet.config.

Another way is as Daniel said that, upload it to your VSTS package feed.

Comment: Thanks... I had gone with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing a local path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 17.1\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore`). If that path doesn't exist on your build agent, the build will fail.

The best solution is going to be to set up a Packages feed in VSTS, upload your packages to that, and update your project to pull the packages from the private package feed.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will try private package feed  and get back to you if any issues..

Answer (score 1):

I created a nuget.config and selected it in the VSTS build step "nuget restore".
Example:

```
<configuration>
          <packageRestore>
            <add key="enabled" value="True" />
            <add key="automatic" value="True" />
          </packageRestore>
          <activePackageSource>
            <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
          </activePackageSource>
          <packageSources>
            <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
            <add key="DevExpress package source" value="https://nuget.devexpress.com/{yourKeyHere}/api" />
          </packageSources>
        </configuration>
```